# Why socket.io disconnects for every 5 second and then reconnects on client side?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, socket.io, aws-opsworks

This might be a simple question.Any help is really appreciated.

I am using socket.io with express framework  on AWS.

I am running a timer using socket.io .I need to constantly emit server time for each seconds.My sockets get disconnected for every 5 seconds and then reconnects automatically.This causes a break in my timer.I really believe that this won't be a problem with code as everything worked good in my previous server.
Is there any configuration that we need to handle in AWS to avoid such disconnects?

Comment: IMHO, you should rather sync the clocks of the different servers and not emit timer ticks to the other end.... sounds like a ton of unnecessary traffic to me. There are protocols in place for that - both traditional ones and new ones in the context of AVB (IEEE 1588 I think). Then, when your clocks are synced, you can schedule actions in absolute time.

Comment: "icanhazepoch.com – returns the epoch time (also called Unix time)"
- https://major.io/icanhazip-com-faq/

Comment: I failed to mention that the timer has different instance on different entities in a page and it keeps changing each second.In this case the p2p protocol can't help.

Comment: My issue was solved by using long polling connections.